# bounded * o = 0 , limited point prove

Tags: real-analysis

suppose E $\subset$ R and p is limited point of E. and f,g are real valued function on E
if g is bounded  on E and $lim_{x \to p} f(x) = 0 $

$$lim_{x\to p} f(x)g(x) = 0$$

I think I'm doing some part wrong take a look.

$lim_{x \to p} f(x) = 0 $, then |f(x) - 0 | < $\epsilon$
 $\to $   |f(x) | < $\epsilon$

if you choose the f(x) = $\epsilon /2$ < $\epsilon$

THEN  you can write

$$lim_{x \to p} g(x)   =  0/ \epsilon$$......

what does this $0/ \epsilon $ represent ?

and which part did i do wrong?

Comment: Where did you use the fact that $g$ is bounded?

Comment: I'm trying to show g(x) is bounded but failed

Comment: You don't have to show that $g$ is bounded, you're already assuming it.  Read what you're trying to prove again carefully, and make sure to use all of the assumptions given.

Comment: I do not actually prove g(x) is bounded. but I assumed result is true and tried to go back ward proving. But i guess its not working

Comment: That won't work - $p \to q$ is not equivalent to $q \to p$.
What you're thinking of is: assume that $lim_{x\to p} f(x)g(x) \neq 0$ then prove that $g$ is not bounded or (show both) $lim_{x \to p} f(x) \neq 0$. Thus, you've proven what you need.